# display content with animation when scrolled down to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am looking for simplest any cleanest way to display content or blocks of content on my site when scrolled down to it. i mean that i would rather not use any frameworks as are jquery or bootstrap.

i would like to achieve something like is seen on these sites:

http://demo.joomla51.com/?theme=Cashmere

http://www.dropingood.com

what would you recommend me how can i achieve that? i am quite familiar with html5, css3 and javascript.

thanks

Comment: why don't you use a framework for that and stop wasting time trying not to re-invent the wheel? like [Scroll Magic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallax Scrolling is what you're looking for. [How Nike Did it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/12/behind-the-scenes-of-nike-better-world/).
Using existing plugins can help you achieve your desired effect while keeping a low overhead. Here are some examples:

- [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)
- [Superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)
- [Scroll Magic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)
- [Skrollr (Open Source)](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)
- others...

You can also see previous question like so: [Parallax Scrolling @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201242/responsively-animate-page-elements-while-scrolling-using-javascript-edit-paral)

Quick Google searches are your friend!

Comment: He explicitly said he doesn't want to use frameworks or plugins.

Comment: Plugins offer much better cross-browser support than just trying to hack away a single route for hours/days. I'm also against having unnecessary overhead, but many of these have a low footprint. Plus as balexandre mentioned, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: i try to avoid libraries and frameworks and try to "re-invent the wheel" simply because of the control and the speed, even if that means a little bit more of my work. i try do a lot on speed optimization.

but due to that that this particular site of mine is very simple and commercial, i will probably use one of above libraries. but if anyone has any other solution without them, please share.

i didn't know how one does say to this type of scrolling (i.e. Parallx Scrolling), this is why i didn't find my answer before.

thank you all.